# Form with target="_blank" - new window AND loading page

Tags: javascript, html, forms

After submiting a form, a new page should open to be printed as pdf.
But by doing it like that `<form action="page.php" method="POST" target="_blank">` the form with all the information still exists which is very, very bad. Instead of still showing the page with the form, I would now like to load another page within this windows/tab AND open 
the print-window. With php and headers it's not possible, but with javascript should be right?
But how? I'm not used to javascript, so I have no idea how to handle this problem, but do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an onsubmit event to the form, f.ex:

```
document.getElementById('form').onsubmit = function() {
    window.location = '/anotherpage.html';
}
```

This assumes that the form has an ID of "form".

Comment: Are you sure the submit still works in all cases? I'd wrap the `location` update in a 1-msec `setTimeout` callback just to be on the safe side.

Comment: I think so, since the form is submitted in a blank target. But I havent tested this in a lot of browsers so there could be race conditions.

Comment: So I tested it like that, but it's still not reloading. `<form action="startaction.php" method="POST" onsubmit="document.getElementById('form').onsubmit = function() {
    window.location = 'orders.php?highlighted=t';
};" target="_blank" id="form">` Should it be like that? I don't have any experiences in javascript, so I am not sure about it.

Comment: Don’t put it in the onsubmit attribute, just place it in a script tag.

Comment: I was going to say that this wasn't working as well, but then I pulled my foot out of my mouth and realized jQuery selectors aren't the same as DOM elements haha.  Too bad ol buddy couldn't accept this answer.